# How to get Phone Number and Email if my user Logs in using Google Sign in Android

Tags: java, android, google-signin

I am using Firebase for my Backend. One of my activities shows the "User Details", so when my user signs in using Google, I am able to get his Name but not his Phone Number or Email address. Is there a way I can fetch registered Phone Number and Email from Gmail?

I am fetching data using-

```
FirebaseUser userF= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                tvMail.setText(userF.getEmail());
                tvName.setText(userF.getDisplayName());
                tvNumber.setText(userF.getPhoneNumber());
```

And I using Firebase Google Sign in as shown here-
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/google-login-android/#Adding-Google-Sign-In-Button-to-Activity (Simply copy pasted this code)

Edit- I added email coz now I am unable to get Email also!

Comment: Please post code of your activities... both registration and user details

Comment: Are you using firebase google sign in ?

Comment: @NensiKasundra Yes I am!

Comment: To get the Phone number you need to ask your user to enter it in some activity and then upload the number to your database